# Java/Android: Native API to transform hours, minutes and seconds in milliseconds

Tags: java, android, time, milliseconds, timeunit

I have created my own method to transform hours, minutes and seconds in milliseconds. It seems to work fine.

I would prefer to use some Java/Android API to do this task.

TimeUnit provides me the reverse: milliseconds to hours, minutes and seconds.

Here goes my code:

```
class SomeUtilsClass {
    public static long toMilliseconds(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
        return ((hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds) * 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);` , `TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);` and `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds);` ?

Comment: Actually no. What about something like my function. It passes all the three units ... (I know, I'm wanting too much :P)

Comment: @Thom Thom Thom can you check answer and let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine and should work perfectly, but if you want to use Java/Android API to do this task you can change your function like this:

```
    public static long toMilliseconds(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
            return (TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes) + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds));
    }
```

PS: You'll have the same result with both functions.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use calendar API for get time TimeInMillis. using java API**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

final Calendar calEventstart=Calendar.getInstance();
calEventstart.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute);
calEventstart.getTimeInMillis();
```